# How to Add validation for div tag using JQUERY unobtrusive?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using "JQUERY unobtrusive" java script for validation. I am using one label and one text box control inside the div tag. When I click on Submit button I need to mark the background color of entire div(divName) as Red.

```
   <div class="form-group" id="divName">
    <label for="your-name-id">Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="yourname" id="your-name-id" placeholder="Please enter your name"      
  </div>
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried so far first... Then we might be able to diagnose the specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You have something called `highlight` and `unhighlight` option in **jquery validation plugin** which you can use to highlight `element`'s closest `parent` as below:

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    //errorClass is a class which will have background-color as red CSS and validClass will have background-color as green CSS
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

For more info check the documentation **[here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)**